# multipe dropdown to be inserted in database one column per dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, database, drop-down-menu

i have 27 dropdowns in my page. but i only show 6 of them because its too long.

```
        <label>Empty META description</label> 
        <select>
            <option name="25" value="1">Ok</option>
            <option name="25" value="2">Information</option>
            <option name="25" value="3">Warning</option>
            <option name="25" value="4">Danger</option>
        </select>

        <label>Duplicate META descriptions</label> 
        <select>
            <option name="26" value="1">Ok</option>
            <option name="26" value="2">Information</option>
            <option name="26" value="3">Warning</option>
            <option name="26" value="4">Danger</option>
        </select>

        <label>Too long META description</label> 
        <select>
            <option name="27" value="1">Ok</option>
            <option name="27" value="2">Information</option>
            <option name="27" value="3">Warning</option>
            <option name="27" value="4">Danger</option>
        </select>
```

i want to insert them in my database one column per dropdown. how shall i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Either comma separate them to fix them in one column & retrieve them by exploding the commas

Or

Create a new table & store the dropdown options with the dropdown ID.

Table :

```
DropDown_ID   DropDown_Value
25                  1 
25                  2
25                  3
25                  4
26                  1
26                  2
26                  3
26                  4
27                  1
..
..
```

Comment: how will the new table look like?

Comment: Gave you the sample. You could also add another column in the above table to add dropdown text like `OK', `Information`,etc.